# Getting below error when I am trying to install Oracle 12c Release 2 on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, centos7, rhel7

Getting below error when I am trying to install Oracle 12c Release 2 on RHEL 7.

```
[oracle@oracledb database]$ ./runInstaller
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 10828 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 2559 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
    >>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before

continuing with the installation,

Continue? (y/n) [n] y
```

Comment: I can't find any actual question in your post. Please read [How do I ask a good question](//$SITEURL/help/how-to-answer) and try to rewrite your question so that it matches the site quidelines. (also, please re-read the error message that you included in your post; it tells you all you should need to know!)

Comment: Actually I tried some solutions like xhost +<computername> & then xhost +<computername>:0.0 still persisting the same issue (Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo.).

Comment: Do you actually have an X server running on the machine you are connecting from?
Have you connected directly as oracle, or have you used su or sudo to become that user?

Comment: I tried to install as oracle.

Comment: I did not ask how you tried to install. I asked how you connected to the server on which you are trying to install.

Comment: You should at least include relevant parts of the `/usr/bin/xdpyinfo` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it seems you need to set the DISPLAY variable

```
DISPLAY=*hostname*:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/EPMIS/ch05s03s02s03.html

Comment: Rather than manually setting the `DISPLAY` variable, it is probably better to find out why it wasn't automatically set in the first place.